# UICollectionViewCell not filling screen width

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I am trying to make my `UICollectionView`'s cells fill the whole width, but it just looks like this:

[image]

I tried something like this:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height+140)
    }
```

But it doesn't do anything. Tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `sizeForItemAt` instead of `sizeForItemAtIndexPath`. sizeForItemAtIndexPath Asks the delegate for the size of the specified item’s cell.

You need to Use Swift 3+:

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    return CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height+140)
}
```